# find the annual per capita spending for personal consumption in doller?

Tags: calculus, economics

Total annual spent of a country is $ \ \$ 9 \ $ trillion for personal consumption . If total population is $ 250 \ $ million , then **find the annual per capita spending for personal consumption  in doller ?**

**Answer:**

total expenditure= $ \ 9 \ $ trillion= $ \ 9 \times 10^6 \ $ million

Total population =$ 250 \ million \ $ .

Hence annual per capita for personal spending = $ \frac {9 \times 10^6}{250}=  ? \ \ person /year $

**I am just unable to find the result in $ person/year $ unit .**

**Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit for per capita spending is $\frac {dollars}{person \cdot year}$ because it is the amount each person spends in one year.  The annual total spending is $9 \cdot 10^{12} \frac {dollars}{year}$  divided by $250 \cdot 10^6 persons$ giving units of $\frac {dollars}{person\cdot year}$

Comment: How $ \ 9 \cdot 10^{12} \ $ came ?  Should not it be $ \ 9 \cdot 10^6 \ $ ?